# Unable to Access Redux Store Data in React Component

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a React application where I'm trying to fetch and store data from Firestore using Redux. I have set up the Redux store, dispatched an action to fetch the data, and I can see that the data is successfully stored in the Redux store. However, when I try to access this data in my component, it returns undefined.

Here's how I've configured my Redux store:`enter code here`

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { wishListSlice } from "../Features/wishListFeature/WishList" 
import { CartListSlice } from "../Features/cartListFeature/CartList"
import LoadDataFireStore from "../Features/dataFromFireStore/LoadDataFireStore"

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    wishList: wishListSlice.reducer,
    cartList: CartListSlice.reducer,
    fireStore: LoadDataFireStore
  }
})
```

I'm using an async action to fetch data from Firestore and store it in the Redux store. The action seems to be working correctly, and I can see the data in the Redux DevTools.

Here's the code for the async action:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { firebaseFireStoreDB } from '../../FirebaseConfiguration/Firebase';
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

const initialState = { data: [] };

const LoadDataFromFireStore = createSlice({
  name: "DataFromFireStore",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    loadFromFireStore: (state, action) => {
      state.data = action.payload;
    }
  }
})

export function getProducts() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const collectionRef = collection(firebaseFireStoreDB, "products");
    const productdata = [];
    await getDocs(collectionRef)
      .then((productData) => {
        productData.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          productdata.push({ ...doc.data(), id: Number(doc.id) });
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error while fetching... " + error);
      });
    dispatch(loadFromFireStore(productdata));
  }
}

export const { loadFromFireStore } = LoadDataFromFireStore.actions;
export default LoadDataFromFireStore.reducer;
```

In my component, I'm trying to access the data from the Redux store like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Row, Col, Spin } from "antd"
import { getProducts } from '../../Features/dataFromFireStore/LoadDataFireStore';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import Product from './Product';

function Products() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProducts());
  }, []);

  const productsData = useSelector(state => state.fireStore);

  console.log("If products are shown, then the Redux state data is successfully loaded");
  console.log(productsData);

  return (
    <div className='ProductsContainer'>
      <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>OUR PRODUCTS</h2>
      <Row gutter={[20, 35]} className='GridRowStyling'>
        {productsData ? (
          productsData.map(productData => (
            <Col className='GridColumn' key={productData.id}>
              <Product data={productData} />
            </Col>
          ))
        ) : (
          <Spin size='large' />
        )}
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Products;
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Can anyone help me understand why I can't access the data in my component, even though it's correctly stored in the Redux store?

Answer (score 0):

The fireStore state is `{ data: [] }` and that state invariant appears to be maintained.

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    wishList: wishListSlice.reducer,
    cartList: CartListSlice.reducer,
    fireStore: LoadDataFireStore, // <-- state.fireStore
  }
});
```

```js
const initialState = {
  data: [] // <-- state.fireStore.data
};

const LoadDataFromFireStore = createSlice({
  name: "DataFromFireStore",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    loadFromFireStore: (state, action) => {
      state.data = action.payload; // <-- state.fireStore.data
    }
  }
});
```

The UI isn't accessing the `state.fireStore.data` value though.

```js
const productsData = useSelector(state => state.fireStore); // <-- { data: [] }

...

productsData.map(productData => ( // <-- {}.map -> undefined, can't invoke
  <Col className='GridColumn' key={productData.id}>
    <Product data={productData} />
  </Col>
))
```

`productsData` is only `state.fireStore` which is an object and doesn't have a `map` property.

Update to any of the following that access the `data` array:

```js
const productsData = useSelector(state => state.fireStore.data);

...

productsData.length ? (
  productsData.map(productData => (
    <Col className='GridColumn' key={productData.id}>
      <Product data={productData} />
    </Col>
  ))
) : ...
```

or

```js
const { data: productsData } = useSelector(state => state.fireStore);

...

productsData.length ? (
  productsData.map(productData => (
    <Col className='GridColumn' key={productData.id}>
      <Product data={productData} />
    </Col>
  ))
) : ...
```

or

```js
const productsData = useSelector(state => state.fireStore);

...

productsData.data.length ? (
  productsData.data.map(productData => (
    <Col className='GridColumn' key={productData.id}>
      <Product data={productData} />
    </Col>
  ))
) : ...
```

Comment: thank you! but now i want to call my firebase function at App compoent but I can't fetching only returning the initial state of state could you help me?

Comment: @GulzarAhamed Is that related to the issue in this post, or is this something else? What Firebase function are you referring to that you want to call? Are you saying that you are dispatching the `getProducts` action, but that the `state.firestore.data` state isn't updating as expected? What is the value of `productdata` in the `getProducts` action creator function? What is the value of `action.payload` in the reducer function? Are these what you expect? Do you have the Redux dev-tools enabled and the browser extension installed so you can inspect the store in real-time?

Comment: Hi, actually i called firebase function when when Products  component rendering but now i want to call the same  getProducts  fuction in  useEffect of App component so that it is available to all component  as a best practice but when i do the same it only redux state gives only the initial state not loaded data  i hope u understood

Comment: @GulzarAhamed It looks like you are already dispatching `getProducts` from a `useEffect` hook. Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "redux state gives only the initial state not loaded data"? Did you apply the solution I have suggested to select the state correctly? Have you verified your redux state is updated as you are expecting? What is the value of `productData` in the `getProducts` action creator function? Do you have the Redux dev-tools enabled and the browser extension installed so you can inspect the store in real-time?

Comment: good day, yes I do enabled that redux dev-tool extension and what  my intention is when i call the  getProducts action creator function in App component 
 like what  I did the same thing in Product component and using the useSelector hook to access the state, but it's only returning the initial state value defined in my slice, and I'm expected it to return the value that the getProducts action creator function returns.

Comment: @GulzarAhamed Ok, so I've gathered now that you are dispatching `getProducts` in the `App` component. Have you checked (1) the state has updated as expected using the redux-devtool to inspect the actions and store value, and (2) that you are selecting the same `state.fireStore.data` state in `App`? You may need to edit your post to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with so we can see what it's doing.